# how to access to data from a class which is stored in another class in python?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code. I got a problem when i want to print the information inside the class 'pokemon'

```
class trainer(object):

def __init__(self, name, pokemons = [], money = 0):
    self.name = name
    self.pokemons = pokemons
    self.money = money
```

this is my first class which has every pokemon per trainer

```
class pokemon(object):

def __init__(self, name, attribute, attacks = {}, health = '==========='):
    self.name = name
    self.attribute = attribute
    self.health = health
    self.attacks = attacks
```

The other class where I take the pokemon to import to the other class

```
class fight():

def __init__(self, fighter1, fighter2):
    self.fighter1 = fighter1
    self.fighter2 = fighter2

def fighting(self):
    if len(Trainer1.pokemons) >= 1 and len(Trainer2.pokemons) >= 1:
        print('{} wanna fight against {}'.format(Trainer1.name, Trainer2.name))
        keepgoing = True
        print('{} got this Pokemons: '.format(Trainer1.name))
        i = 0
        for i in Trainer1.pokemons:
            print(i)
        #while (keepgoing):

    else:
        print('You gotta have pokemons to fight')  
        return False
```

I thought that creating a class named fight for getting in battle would be the most wise idea but I'd like to know another method to do it

```
Pokemon1 = pokemon('Charizard', 'Fire', attacks={'1':'ball fire', '2':'cut', '3':'fire blast', '4':'mega kick'})
Pokemon2 = pokemon('Charmander', 'fire', attacks={'1':'blast', '2':'scratch', '3':'heat', '4':'tear'})
Trainer1 = trainer('Santiago', pokemons=[Pokemon1, Pokemon2])

Pokemon3 = pokemon('Charizard', 'Fire', attacks={'1':'ball fire', '2':'cut', '3':'fire blast', '4':'mega kick'})
Pokemon4 = pokemon('Charmander', 'fire', attacks={'1':'blast', '2':'scratch', '3':'heat', '4':'tear'})
Trainer2 = trainer('Alejandra', pokemons=[Pokemon3, Pokemon4])
```

Okay my problem is in the class fight. when i want to print the names of the pokemons i get the following message:

```
Santiago got this Pokemons: 
<__main__.pokemon object at 0x000002AAD9B64D00>
<__main__.pokemon object at 0x000002AAD9B92DF0>
```

i know that the pokemon class has various instances, but how can i access to them?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly... change Traner1.name to Trainer1.pokemons[0].name

Comment: I already tried to do it, but still the same

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier, I recommend that you implement the `__str__` dunder method on `pokemon`. This will resolve the issue that you are seeing right now, and make future `print`s of `pokemon` much easier.

That would look something like this:

```py
class pokemon(object):

    def __init__(self, name, attribute, attacks = {}, health = '==========='):
        self.name = name
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.health = health
        self.attacks = attacks

    def __str__(self):
        return "Pokemon: %s (Health: %11s)" % (self.name, self.health)
```

When you print the `'Charmander'` pokemon, it'll look something like this:

> `Pokemon: Charmander (Health: ===========)`

Of course, you can change the return of the `__str__` to return whatever you want out of the `pokemon`.

Comment: Thank dude, this is very helpful

Comment: Thanks! Consider upvoting and accepting this answer if it helped you.